# What do the progress bars on the Alethzero "blockchain download" window mean?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, cpp-ethereum, alethzero

I'm exploring Alethzero. **What do the progress bars in the "blockchain download" window mean?** I'm seeing this:

[image]

I'm assuming this relates to the progress in dowloading the blockchain but I can't work out what the different bars relate to.